# postfix - forward mail for unknown clients to another server: a working example, please

Tags: postfix, mail-forwarding

I need to forward(relay) mail from one postfix server to another, so that they are "answerable" with the same address as the original ones. Also, I need all mail from accounts on server 2 which are destined for other accounts on server 2 to be delivered locally, while all other should be relayed to third server which is actually a mail cluster.

So, something like this:

- mail for user@my.dom goes to cluster.other.dom
- cluster.other.dom sees it should relay it to mail.my.dom which is where postfix server 1 has all the mailboxes as virtual
- mail.my.dom check its transport/virtual/aliases and sees it should relay it to mail2.my.dom where postfix server 2 has only some mailboxes, and accepts mail for some users in two domains: my.dom and mail2.my.dom
- mail2.my.dom finds user@my.dom as local user and accepts the message

This part actually works, problems are in other direction...like:

- user@my.dom at mail2.my.dom wants to send mail locally to user2@my.dom or user3@mail2.my.dom which also resides at mail2.my.dom - postfix accepts it only if *mydestination=localhost*
- user@my.dom at mail2.my.dom wants to send mail to user123@my.dom which resides on mail.my.dom (the first postfix server) - postfix on mail2.my.dom (the second server) looks at it's tables, can't find user123@my.dom and returns "User unknown" - but, it should relay the mail back to cluster.other.dom or mail.my.dom (first server)
- user@my.dom which resides at mail2.my.dom receives mail from user123@gmail.com but when he tries to reply, it goes out as user@mail2.my.dom - not as user@my.dom. And since mail2.my.dom is not visible from the network (it is internal and accessible through VPN only), further replies from user123@gmail.com try to go to user@mail2.my.dom which fails since mail2.my.dom is not accessible nor is MX for anything

Now, the greatest problem is that I can not make this relaying of non-local users happen - I've tried all the solutions I could find (most of them are like 5+ years old) and none of them work.
Either there's no relaying, or everything is relayed to the cluster (which of course is also wrong).

Is this even possible? To make postfix check it's local maps/databases and if user is not found, simply send it through a relay server, without any address rewriting, substitution etc (meaning user@my.dom does not become user@mail2.my.dom)?

To further clarify, I have defined only these regarding virtual*:

```
virtual_transport = procmail
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf    
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
```

Both mail domains (my.dom and mail2.my.dom) are in virtual-mailbox-domains, and all users in both domains are in virtual-mailbox-maps, and all of them have aliases same as their email, in virtual-alias-maps.

I do not know if I made it too complicated/hard to understand, I'm sorry if I did, but I needed to make the situation as clear as possible before eventually giving more details.

Part of my main.cf:

```
mydestination = localhost 
myhostname = mail2.my.dom 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128 
myorigin = /etc/mailname 
relayhost = [cluster.other.dom] 
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf 
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf 
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf 
virtual_transport = procmail 
smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient = no 
smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender = no
```

Thanks.

Comment: it'd have helped if you also posted your config files, as a starting point

Comment: Well, I have tried many versions so right now,main.cf is kind of a mess...

Comment: Besides, this system won't let me post my config, it says "too long"...how to do it?
Should I post a link to pastebin or something external or is there a way to add a longer comment than 500 characters?

Comment: Part of my main.cf:

`mydestination = localhost
myhostname = mail2.my.dom
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
relayhost = [cluster.other.dom]
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_transport = procmail
smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient = no
smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender = no`